# Rails - How can I check if a variable exists and also if it has a certain value in one statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined

Currently if it doesn't exists I get a the `undefined local variable or method` error.

How can I check the value of the variable and also account for it not existing at all.

I thought `&&` was the deal but:

```
if defined? aaa && aaa == '123' then puts aaa end

NameError: undefined local variable or method `aaa' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, you need the parenthetical like `defined?(aaa)` otherwise it is evaluating the entire expression `aaa && aaa == '123'` as if it were `defined?(aaa && aaa == '123')`. So your code is really doing this:

```
if defined?(aaa && aaa == '123') # returns "expression" string, and thus true
  puts aaa # the error comes from this part, since aaa is not defined.
end
```